# sql json colm join other table

Tags: php, sql, json, join

i have students_id column  in Group table.but its in json  format. and i want join students table to Group, by students_id .  is there a way to do it  ?

Comment: You probably need to show your schema for the Group and students tables. And some sample data. Else it's just guesswork, but something like `select * from group join students on group.students_id like concat('%',students.id,'%')` might just work (or work well enough)

Comment: You should maybe specify the dbms in use, too (mysql?)

Answer (score 0):

Going on a limb here and here's the results:

```
 SELECT s.*,g.* FROM students s, group g WHERE s.students_id = g.students_id
```